# Form action not working for form inside form

Tags: angularjs, html

```
<div class="h4 form-group">Tariff Changeset</div>
    <ng-form novalidate class="form-horizontal offer-form" name="offerForm">
<div class="btn-toolbar form-group" ng-hide="tariffSaved">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Save()"><span>Save</span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Done()"><span>Done</span></button>            
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group" ng-show="tariffSaved">
            <a class="link" href="/services/Tariff/GetChangesetAsFile{{prodCodes}}">Download data</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a class="link" ng-click="readyToUpload=!readyToUpload">Upload data</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <form action="/Data/TariffExcelUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    Select image to upload:
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
                </form>

        </div>
    </ng-form>    
</div>
```

So when i click on "Upload Image", the action (action="/Data/TariffExcelUpload") is not getting hit. In fact nothing is happening. Is this due to form inside ng-form ?? or some other issue with this HTML

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not do that.
Check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: @lonDen Nested `form` never work togethere, but here I think `form` inside inside `ng-form` should work... as form is working as individual in `ng-form`,